# Make Angular component stylesheet work with sub-components

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular12

I'm relatively new to Angular, and I have a doubt about component stylesheets.

I have an Angular 12 app and created a component named `my-component`. The template of the  component in question is something like this:

**my-component.html**

```
<div>
  ...some html...
  <some-other-angular-component></some-other-angular-component>
  ...some other html...
</div>
```

`some-other-angular-component` is another component, either from the app itself or a third party library.

Now, what I want to do in `my-component` is apply some CSS rules to the contents of `some-other-angular-component`. I know that the HTML it generates contains classes that I can target, so I tried to add this to my component CSS:

**my-component.scss**

```
.some-other-angular-component-inner-class {
  background-color: red;
}
```

However, this doesn't work, it appears that the component's CSS file only applies rules to the HTML defined directly in the component's template, not the HTML generated by sub-components.

Is there a way to make this work? I find myself having to add my CSS to the webapp's main `style.scss` file, even when I want to apply the rule only to the particular `some-other-angular-component` instance inside of `my-component`. It makes styling confusing and needlessly fragmented. Is this intended, or what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may want to look into [View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation#no-encapsulation).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-no-encapsulation',
  template: `
    <h2>None</h2>
    <div class="none-message">No encapsulation</div>
  `,
  styles: ['h2, .none-message { color: red; }'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class NoEncapsulationComponent { }
```

These styles will be added to head and will be applicable to other components as well if style rule matches.

Please note, with this you are **only** enabling this behaviour for just **this** component. Chances of overlapping CSS rules is still there but is lot less in comparison to directly putting styles in `style.css`.

I will also suggest that you add `.class` or `#id` attribute in mark up to ensure that your rules don't overlap by default.

For example:

```
.my-component .rule-one {
}
```

It will ensure that my rules are only applied are on component that has this class applied on it.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly it!